# Validate file path with regular expression angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I need to check if my input is correct. It must look like `Folder/game.dll` Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" name="addRelativePath" ng-model="addGameModel.RelativePath" class="form-control" required ng-pattern="validationRegex">
```

My angularJs:

```
 $scope.validationRegex = / (\w+[^.]\/)+\w+.dll /;
```

What is wrong? Nothing happend whem I submit my form and expression in input is incorrect.

Comment: Try (\w+[^.]\/)+(\w+)\.dll also nice site for testing: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Which part of your input should be like this `Folder/game.dll` ?

Comment: The data that I enter should look  such as: the game and the folder in which it resides. We need to make sure that the user has entered data is on such a model. By the way it does not matter which way the separator : / or \

Comment: @SvetaAntrapovich I really can't understand what's your point.. Anyway this `/\s(\w[^.]+\/)\.dll\s/` can be improved-version of your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking form validy thorough the form controller property $valid? It should be checked if not angular will submit the form

```
<form novalidate name="vm.form" ng-submit="vm.form.$valid && vm.submit()">
</form>
```